# Does the augmented matrix have no solution??

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I'm preparing for an exam and one of the sample papers had this question.

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
    1 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 8 \\
    1 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 8 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & 2 & 2 & 2 &6 
  \end{array}\right]
$$

Since $R_4=2\times R_3$ then that means that the matrix has no solution right??

Comment: What does it mean that a matrix has no solution???

Comment: It has more than just having 'no' solutions. In fact, they are infinitely many solutions! Set the last two variable as arbitrary parameters.

Comment: Just because two equations are dependent doesn't mean that there are no solutions. Consider the system $x + y = 1$, $2x + 2y = 2$...

Comment: no solutions occur when a zero row equals something not equal to 0

Comment: How about $(2,1,2,0)$?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*:- For the system $Ax=b$, where $A$ is $m×n$, $x$ is $n×1$, $b$ is $m×1$, the augmented matrix is $C=[A:b]$ and it has

1. a unique solution if $rank(A)=rank(C)=n$
2. infinitely many solutions if $rank(A)=rank(C)<n$
3. no solution if $rank(A)\ne rank(C)$